# Estructuras Iterativas en c

Tags: c

Tengo un ejercicio para realizar un programa en C usando estructuras iterativas:

> Elaborar un programa que permita procesar varias notas de venta de una
> empresa que vende hojas de aluminio. Calcular la nota de venta
> considerando la cantidad de hojas compradas por el precio por hoja.
> Considerar un descuento de acuerdo con lo siguiente:
>
> • Si el cliente es tipo 1 se le descuenta el 8 % 
> • Si el cliente es tipo 2 se le descuenta el 12 %
>
> Por cada venta imprimir la siguiente información:
>
> Subtotal:         $9,999.99 
> Descuento:             999.99  
> Total de nota de venta:   $9,999.99
>
> Al final del reporte imprimir:
>
> Cantidad de notas de venta en el día: 99  
> Total de notas de venta en el día:    $9,999.99 
> Cantidad de tipos de cliente tipo 1 en el día: XX  
> Cantidad de tipos de cliente tipo 2 en el día: XX

Este es mi código, tengo duda en el orden que debería ingresarlo ya que no me funciona(alguna recomendación?).

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define preciohojas 60.00
//1.Realizar un programa en C usando estructuras iterativas: 
int main (int argc, char** args) 
{
int i; 
float clientes, canthojas;
int subtotal, descuento, total;
int cliente, regular;
 

printf("Ingresa la cantidad de clientes \n"); 
scanf("%d", &clientes); 

for (i=0; i<clientes; i++)
{

printf("Selecciona el tipo de cliente, 1,2 o regular \n"); 

scanf("%d", &cliente); 

}

if (cliente==1) 

{ 

printf("Ingresa la cantidad de hojas \n"); 
scanf("%d", &canthojas); 

subtotal= canthojas*preciohojas;
printf("Subtotal; %.2f", subtotal); 

descuento= (subtotal*15)/100;
printf("Descuento; %.2f", descuento);

total= subtotal-descuento; 
printf("Total de nota de venta; %.2f",total);

} 


else if (cliente==2) 

{ 

printf("Ingresa la cantidad de hojas \n"); 
scanf("%f", &canthojas); 

subtotal= canthojas*preciohojas;
printf("Subtotal; %.2f", subtotal); 

descuento= (subtotal*25)/100;
printf("Descuento; %.2f", descuento);

total= subtotal-descuento; 
printf("Total de nota de venta; %.2f",total);

} 

else if (cliente== regular) 

{ 

printf("Ingresa la cantidad de hojas \n"); 
scanf("%f", &canthojas); 

subtotal= canthojas*preciohojas;
printf("Total; %.2f", subtotal); 

} 

else 

{ 

printf("Numero invalido \n"); 

} 

    printf("total de ventas del dia:\t%d\n", clientes);



printf("i= %d \n", i); 

system("pause");

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cuando decis que no te funciona, que es lo que pasa? tenes un error? el codigo no hace lo que tiene que hacer? que hace y que deberia hacer?

Comment: Podrías por favor, editar tu pregunta e indicarnos a qué te refieres con que no funciona? Qué error sale? Qué dato muestra y cuál debería salir? Con qué valores lo estás probando? Aquí quienes intentan responder suelen (solemos) replicar los problemas que nos indican usando el código y los datos de prueba, pero es necesario que nos cuentes qué pasa y qué debería pasar

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda?